# What is the fewest vertices a non-planar subgraph of the Knight's graph can have?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, chessboard, forbidden-subgraphs

I was wondering about the title question:

> What is the fewest vertices a non-planar subgraph of [the Knight's graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_graph) can have?

I have found a subgraph with <s>14</s> 10 vertices that is non-planar

> [image]
>  
>  Contract the blue edges to get $K_{3,3}$

And it is pretty easy to show that any subgraph of the knight's graph of size 7 is planar.  I just used a proof by exhaustion, showing that you can't make $K_5$ in two contractions and you can't make $K_{3,3}$ in one.  I will leave the proof out of this question for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Are you using "size" in the technical sense of "number of edges?"

Comment: @saulspatz Oh yes good point I am not I meant number of vertices, I've updated the question.